# group ids of collection into array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Getting all documents id in an array based on query and : 
I tried with this,

1. `db.getCollection('attendances').find({ "shift" : ObjectId("59ff8ff8c88f1550775ecb17")},{_id : 1})`
2. db.getCollection('employees').aggregate([
       {

   ```
   $match : {"organization" : ObjectId("59f83c17fa62ad79d2d94b9c")}

   },{
       $project: {
           _id : 1
       }
   }
   ])
   ```

and getting response like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f83c19fa62ad79d2d94ba1")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9a43cfa62ad79d2d951bd")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9a43efa62ad79d2d951bf")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9a440fa62ad79d2d951c0")
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9a441fa62ad79d2d951c1")
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9a443fa62ad79d2d951c2")
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f9a445fa62ad79d2d951c3")
}
```

as i know i am finding all documents based on condition and projecting only there ids i.e why i am getting object of documents. But i want array of ids like:

```
   _id":[ObjectId("59f83c19fa62ad79d2d94ba1"),ObjectId("59f9a43cfa62ad79d2d951bd"), ObjectId("59f9a43efa62ad79d2d951bf") ]
```

How can i achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`cursor.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) i.e `db.getCollection('attendances').find({ "shift" : ObjectId("59ff8ff8c88f1550775ecb17")},{_id : 1}).map( d => d._id )`

Comment: Thanks. it works :)